# Best practise for developing Google App Engine OAuth2 Java API application on local machine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-drive-api

I'm trying to debug a Google App Engine project locally and that application uses Google's OAuth2 API access (Google Drive access). I mapped a sub-domain to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file and ensured that sub-domain didn't return a 404 publicly (Google does a basic test to see if there's anything there at the redirect location) and the redirect correct executes the servlet on my local machine.

The problem is that I seem to have an anonymous quota now and quickly exceeded my limit for the day. Is there a way to link me to my account with this setup to get the non-anonymous quota?

Comment: Have you looked over this documentation: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to enable Drive API in addition to Drive SDK in Google APIs Console